# SSRS Report Group

Tags: ssrs-2008

I want to get a tabular result like below
[image]

My query is returning the result like below

[image]

Can anyone suggest me a way to do this using SSRS?
I have tried grouping, but couldn't get the expected output. I am new to ssrs reporting. Please provide a detailed solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Set up a **Tablix**, grouped by *Doctor Code*, and add a Group Header row based on this group. Display all fields in this row except *Product Sampled*.

In the *Product Sampled* **Textbox**, insert a **Tablix** directly into the **Textbox**. Set this **Tablix** up to show only one detail row, set to display *Product Sampled*.

What this achieves is that you have one row per *Doctor Code*, but within each of these group rows you will have a table embedded to display each of the *Product Sampled* rows. Because the  *Product Sampled* **Tablix** is embedded in a Group scope, it will display the *Product Sampled* details for each *Doctor Code* as required.

**Edit after comment:**

I will demonstrate with a simplified example. First generate some sample data:

[image]

Next, set up a table with a group based on **DoctorCode**, which will look something like this:

[image]

Note we haven't filled in **ProductSampled** yet.

Next, go to Toolbox and drag a table object into the blank **ProductSampled** cell. Remove the header and all but one of the columns, then set the column in the table to the **ProductSampled** field. It should look something like this:

[image]

When you run this report with the sample data, it works as required:

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain the second paragraph. Since I am new SSRS, I can't follow the steps even its simple. Thanks in advance

Comment: @SaliniS, I have added a simplified example with screenshots and output.